# Youtube embed API and external JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I have read the basics of the YouTube API and have it working on my webpage with no problems. However I would like to be able to use the video's state to trigger or stop certain functions which I have written in an external JS file. I'd really appreciate any help!

At present I have the following embedded into my HTML file just after the iframe itself:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
    player = new YT.Player('MyVideoID',{
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event){
    event.target.playVideo();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        var slideTimeMS = 10000; /* This is a variable which exists in my external file which I would like the player state to manipulate
    }
}
```

The code above in itself works fine but as I said before I would like to move it to an external file so I can, for example, pause a carousel when the video is playing etc., the functions for which are already in said JS file.

Can anyone tell me how I could successfully make this accessible in the other file?

Thanks so much for any help!

Mark

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who this might help, here was the solution I eventually found:

Iframe embedded in HTML as normal but with no JS done in the HTML whatsoever. In my JS file I have the following:

```
var myPlayerState;
$(function(){
    var yt_int, yt_players={},
        initYT = function() {
            $("IDOrClassOfMyVideo").each(function() {
                yt_players[this.id] = new YT.Player(this.id,
                {
                    events: {
                        'onReady' : onPlayerReady,
                        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                    }
                });
            });
        };

    $.getScript("//www.youtube.com/player_api", function() {
        yt_int = setInterval(function(){
            if(typeof YT === "object"){
                initYT();
                clearInterval(yt_int);
            }
        },500);
    });
```

Then the functions in the rest of the code work as normal!

Comment: I've had so much trouble with the YT Embed API across so many sites—because I wanted to separate the functionality from the DOM. This is the best solution cross-site. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options:

1. Move the code into the same file as your other JS functions.
2. Move the code into its own file and import it using the script tags **after** the file containing your other JS functions.
3. Use a JS file/module loader like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: Hi arizzle. Thanks a lot for the suggestions. My problem with option 1 - which is my preferred option, for sure - is that it doesn't seem to work. If I lift the code above and put it in my js file, I get no results. I think I'm missing something, perhaps how to refer to the iframe and the API in the html file.

Comment: Do any errors show up in the console when you try to do that? It would help if I could see what the whole js file looks like

Answer (score 1):

[this article](https://chromatichq.com/insights/working-youtube-player-api-iframe-embeds) was very useful for me

```
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    window.player = new window.YT.Player(iframeId, {
        ......
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).